# SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '='

Tags: java, sql-server

This gives syntax error xD, and I also know that is in the url, but really do not quite understand:

```
public String usuario="sa";
public String contraseña="hola";

public String url ="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=ALIBABASE;";

public Connection cn=null;
public Statement st=null;


public Statement Conectar()

{
    try
    {
    Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection( url,usuario,contraseña);
    st=cn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

    }   catch (SQLException i)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, i);

        }
        return st;
    }
```

}

Comment: Hi, you you please edit your Q in English? It would make it easier for more people to help you. As you are new, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I cant see an issue with the url , however please ensure you have loaded the SQL Driver by calling `Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");` before the `DriverManager.getConnection`